# How to find which files are using a particular external library in an Android Studio project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

### The problem

Under "External Libraries" in the project view of an Android Studio project I have these libraries "stax-stax-api:1.0.1@jar" and "xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3@jar". They're causing me problems such that I can't build the project. I can't seem to figure out how they got there or where they're being used.

[image]

[image]

The error message I get when I build right now is:

"*Error:Error: xpp3 defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]*"

The error message is good except that it doesn't tell me who's using this lib in the first place.

### The question

Is there an easy way to find out where they're being used in the project? Or even a way that it's easy but doesn't require looking at every file? It's a multi module project with lots of files. If I could delete them this would tell me but there's no delete option.

This could be something really simple that I'm overlooking. Any help appreciated. Happy to add more info as requested.

### What I've tried

I've tried to "Analyze Dependencies" but it doesn't show me any references that I can see.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that I've also tried `./gradlew app:dependencies` but it only tells me that my project depends on these libraries. I already know this. Is there a way to get some more specific information so I can remove the libraries?

**Update 2:** The accepted answer does work but I needed to redirect console output.

Comment: @cricket_007 the "duplicate" doesn't actually answer my question. I know these things are dependencies but where specifically are they coming from and how can I remove them?

Comment: Ok I've solved the problem but the solution was just luck (by chance I found a dependency that wasn't used that was causing the problem). The supposed "duplicate" unfortunately didn't help but there's no way to mark it as not a duplicate.

Comment: Removing a library can be found in different answers. You ask how to find which libraries are part of others, and that's what the duplicate is for. This shows you the artifactId and groupId, from which your can explicitly exclude from the compiled ones in your project

Comment: @cricket_007 no I ask how to find which files (specifically) depend on a library, not which libraries an entire project depends on. The question is unanswered.

Comment: Also, you really don't need JAR files, do you? `compile 'stax:stax-api:1.0.1'` and `compile 'xpp3:xpp3:1.1.3.3'` should work

Comment: I'm not using those libraries in my dependencies. That's the whole point! No where in my code to I reference them directly. The screenshot is there to help show that I'm referring to the "external libraries" view. The one that gets generated automatically.

Comment: You have a library that *is using them transitively*. Please add the output of the dependency command to the question

Comment: I put the lib back to try and get the output but now it's showing even less output when I run the gradle task. If I run via the terminal the output is cut off so I can't scroll up high enough to see it. Couldn't find how to get more output but haven't looked for very long and it's a different question. I'll try to update the question later when I work out how to do that but need to work on something else now. (who knows maybe it includes the answer).

Comment: If the output is too large for a terminal,  redirect to a file. `./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt`

Comment: ok thanks for the tip. After analysing the results I couldn't see any direct references to the library I added back in. However I think had I not known about this library and followed this tree I would also have solved the issue. So yes I will say now more confidently that it is indeed a duplicate. Thanks for your help! Not sure why the normal gradle task didn't output all that data - when double clicking the task under tasks->help->dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

It will show you the dependencies tree of your project

At this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-display-project-dependency/) it is explained quite well about the command and how to use it.

Use this to redirect console output if it's clipped:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

Comment: I've tried this but it only gives me high level information. Do you know how to make it more specific? I think this is likely the right path though; to find the right Gradle command. I'll have to research Gradle.

Comment: ok this does actually work but I needed the tip I added into your answer from cricket_007

Comment: Thank you, Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Project can be explored in "Project-tool-window" to have a look at the used external libraries which are not visible in "Android tool Window".
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html
That way I solve my problem. Hope it help.[image]